# Creating a histogram to map character frequency

Tags: python, function, loops, histogram

I am creating a function that returns a histogram with each letter of the alphabet and asterisks that map out how many times each character appears in a string. So far I have:

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

def character_frequency_string(text):
    #remove_extraneous function removes anything that is not a letter in the alphabet from the text string
    new_text = remove_extraneous(text)
    
    for char in new_text:
        if char in new_text:
            print(char +' ' + '*'*new_text.count(char))
        if char not in new_text:
            print(char)
```

My docstring is the following (with the outputs as they are right now, incorrect):

```
'''
    Examples:
    >>> character_frequency_string('hello world!')
    h *
    e *
    l ***
    l ***
    o **
    w *
    o **
    r *
    l ***
    d *
    >>> character_frequency_string('testing!')
    t **
    e *
    s *
    t **
    i *
    n *
    g *
    '''
```

The correct output for 'hello world!' would be:

[image]

How could I change my code so that the histogram works as intended (with all of the alphabet in order, displaying an asterisk beside each letter for its character frequency, still displaying letters when they aren't in the text, just with no asterisk.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over `alphabet`:

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
            'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']


def character_frequency_string(text):
    new_text = text
    for char in alphabet:
        print(char + ' ' + '*' * new_text.count(char))


character_frequency_string('hello world!')
```

**Output**

```
a 
b 
c 
d *
e *
f 
g 
h *
i 
j 
k 
l ***
m 
n 
o **
p 
q 
r *
s 
t 
u 
v 
w *
x 
y 
z
```

The above solution has `O(n^2)` time complexity, a more performant alternative is to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following, using a `collections.Counter` and f-strings:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet

def character_frequency_string(text):
    c = Counter(text.lower())
    for x in alphabet:
        print(f"{x} {'*' * c[x]}")

>>> character_frequency_string("hello world!")
a 
b 
c 
d *
e *
f 
g 
h *
i 
j 
k 
l ***
m 
n 
o **
p 
q 
r *
s 
t 
u 
v 
w *
x 
y 
z
```

Some docs:

- [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
- [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase)

Comment: The output does not match the intended one, needs to include the 0 counts also

Answer (score 1):

You could use set for getting the same result

```py
import re
strString = input("Please give input value of the string :")

strString = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z]","",strString)
strString=strString.lower()
print(strString)
a = list(sorted(set(strString.lower())))
for i in range(len(a)):
    count = 0
    for k in range(len(strString)):
        if a[i] == strString[k]:
            count = count + 1
            str(a[i])+"is"+str(count)
            
    print(a[i] + " " + "*" *count)
```

Comment: the print in the loop will show the temporary results as well. Further, punctuation and white spaces are not desired, only alphabetical characters

Comment: Added few lines of code added inoder that punctuation and white spaces are not taken into account ,only alphabet are considered.

Comment: that's good, but keep in mind that you are making the frequency table of the characters contained in the string only, not wrt to the whole alphabet. Notice the also that the result is wrong, the characters are not unique: check with `strString = "Please give input value of the string :"` and see what happens

Comment: Added few lines of code... Now the characters are unique... But my question is that is it required to display all alphabets even if they are not there in given string?

Comment: yes, from the question: _"all of the alphabet in order, displaying an asterisk beside each letter for its character frequency,"_. Check also the image to have a reference

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary approach. Notice the `text` may contain characters which do not belongs to the alphabet such as punctuation and white spaces. In case, such excluded characters are implemented also as `string.punctuation` and `string.whitespace`.

```
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

def character_frequency_string(text, sep='*'):
    d = dict.fromkeys(alphabet, 0)
    for c in tuple(text.lower()):
        if c in d:
            d[c] += 1

    print(*(f'{k} {sep*v}' for k, v in d.items()), sep='\n')


t = 'hello world!'
character_frequency_string(t)
```